# How to redirect rewritten url

Tags: .htaccess

URL is rewritten using following rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/$ category?id=$1
```

to change

```
http://localhost/newsite/category?id=home
```

to following structure

```
http://localhost/newsite/home/
```

Now I tried to redirect, `newsite/category?id=home` to `newsite/home/`, to make clean URL using redirect rule, such as 301, redirect, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this set of rules in `newsite/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /newsite/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /category(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/$ category.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @anubhava..doesn't work.. Please see my updated question with detailed problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559638/cannot-redirect-querystring-url/50560187#50560187

Comment: Doesn't work is not sufficient. What URL did you enter in browser and what error did you get? Test with only these rules in your site root .htaccess, nothing else.

Comment: Is there any way to show htaccess error log ? When adding this line in htaccess, nothing change. I mean when `http://localhost/newsite/category?cat=home` link is visited, then it should automatically change in `http://localhost/ourallnews/home/`. but it doesn't changed, still same url with querystring remained. Only `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]`. changed querystring url, but I can't customize it as it redirectes to `http://localhost/ourallnews/category.php`

Comment: It is because information in your question is different. You wrote URL is `/newsite/category?id=home` but you're saying URL is `/newsite/category?cat=home`. So parameter `id` changed to `cat`. What exactly is correct?

Comment: Actually sir, this problem had ruined my 2 days. I tried with almost answer and guidelines provided in stack-overflow and other sites. I've tried with re-coding several times. So, parameter and file names has changed. I found your code had already worked, but my stupidity to forget to remove chrome-cache ruined me. Many many thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

You missed the .php in the rewrite statement

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/$ category?id=$1
```

change to

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/$ category.php?id=$1
```

Comment: it is typo mistake, it working fine. My question is how to redirect  ?? rewrite is working.. I want to redirect url that contains query string to my custom url which I have created using rewrite rule