# cannot redirect querystring url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to clean url redirecting query string URL. I've tried all answer and rules provided in stackoverflow and in other sites, but nothing changed. I thought it was .htaccess file error, but I found it is working fine to generate other error. I am trying to redirect

```
http://localhost/ourallnews/category.php?cat=News
```

To

```
http://localhost/ourallnews/News/
```

First I tried using this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^ourallnews/category\.php$ /ourallnews/%1? [R=302,L]
```

After that I tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^ourallnews.*$ /ourallnews/%1/? [R=302,L]
```

**Nothing changed.**

I clear browser cache, restart apache but doesn't work. Querystring url is remained.

**Then finally this one brings change.**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

It change

```
http://localhost/ourallnews/category.php?cat=News
```

to

```
http://localhost/ourallnews/category.php
```

But my requirement is show querystring value not URI.

```
http://localhost/ourallnews/news/
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^ourallnews/category\.php$ /ourallnews/%1? [R=302,L]
```

This will redirect `/ourallnews/category.php?cat=value` to `/ourallnews/value` .

Comment: I tried this, but nothing changed. Along with your answer, I tried all answer provided in stackoverflow, but no luck. This one `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]` changed `http://localhost/ourallnews/category.php?cat=News`
to `http://localhost/ourallnews/category.php` But can't fulfill my requirements. Please see updated question. Thanks for your co-operation.

Comment: @AnandHmt What url are you going to and What error do you get?

Comment: Is there any way to show htaccess error log ? When adding this line in htaccess, nothing change. I mean when `http://localhost/ourallnews/category.php?cat=News` link is visited, then it would be automatically changed in `http://localhost/ourallnews/news/`. but it doesn't changed, still same url with querystring remained.

Comment: This rule is working fine for me on my server. I think you have placed it somewhere in your htaccess where it's not being called or being overridden by other rules. Put this at the top of your htaccess  (before other directives) and clear your browser cache to test it.

Comment: I added top, cleared cache, delete and recreate .htaccess adding only this 3 lines, still no luck, Does html/php coding structure affect htaccess rule ? I think the problem is from php/html file

Comment: @AnandHmt Htaccess rules are executed first ( before php and html redirects ) So I don't think the problem is there . Is your htaccess file located in the root folder of your site?

Comment: I found problem, it is in my htaccess file. Thanks now it works

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^ourallnews.*$ /ourallnews/%1/? [R=302,L]
```

Some differences with yours:

`RewriteRule` match:

- `^ourallnews.*$` which will match anything that starts with `ourallnews`
- `^ourallnews/$` which won't match because `$` means end of string without a `category.php`

`RewriteRule` rewrite:

- `/ourallnews/%1/?` is your desired output URL
- There's no need to map to `category.php` in the rewrite result

Comment: I tried this, but nothing changed. Along with your answer, I tried all answer provided in stackoverflow, but no luck. This one `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]` changed `http://localhost/ourallnews/category.php?cat=News`
to `http://localhost/ourallnews/category.php` But can't fulfill my requirements. Please see updated question. Thanks for your co-operation.